# Programmatically identify django many-to-many links

Tags: mysql, django, many-to-many

I'd like to automatically generate a list of an objects many-to-many links.

Let's say I have 5 Models:

```
Model 1 has a M2M link to Model 2
Model 2 has a M2M link to Models 3 and 4
Model 4 has a M2M link to Model 5
```

If the user adds an object to Model 1, I want to give them the option to add another Model 1 or add Model 2

If the user adds an object to Model 2, I want to give them the option to add another Model 2, or add a Model 1, 3, or 4.

If the user adds an object to Model 4, I want to give them the option to add another Model 4 or a Model 5/2.

etc.

Is there a way to detect these relationships (forward and backward) automatically?

Answer (score 2, accepted):

You can access to m2m relation fields via `Model1()._meta.many_to_many` which will return all m2m relations, including `GenericRelations`.