# Programmatically identify django foreignkey links

Tags: mysql, django, one-to-many

Similar to the question I asked [here](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/9112137/programmatically-identify-django-many-to-many-links), if I wanted to list all of the foreign key relationships from a model, is there a way to detect these relationships (forward and backward) automatically?

Specifically, if Model 1 reads

```
class Mdl_one(models.Model):
    name = models.CharField(max_length=30)
```

and Model 2 reads

```
class Mdl_two(models.Model):
    mdl_one = models.ForeignKey(Mdl_one)
    name = models.CharField(max_length=30)
```

Is there some meta command I can run from Mdl_one (like Model_one()._meta.one_to_many) that tells me that mdl_two has a one-to-many foreign key relationship with it?  Simply that mdl_one and mdl_two *can* be connected, not necessarily that any two objects actually *are*?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

This is you are looking for:

```
yourModel._meta.get_all_related_objects()
```

Sample (**Edited**):

```
class Alumne(models.Model):
    id_alumne = models.AutoField(primary_key=True)
    grup = models.ForeignKey(Grup, db_column='id_grup')
    nom_alumne = models.CharField("Nom",max_length=240)
    cognom1alumne = models.CharField("Cognom1",max_length=240)
    cognom2alumne = models.CharField("Cognom2",max_length=240, blank=True)
    ...

class Expulsio(models.Model):                             <---!
    alumne = models.ForeignKey(Alumne, db_column='id_alumne')
    dia_expulsio = models.DateField(blank=True)
    ...


>>> from alumnes.models import Alumne as A
>>> for x in A._meta.get_all_related_objects():
...     print x.name
... 
horaris:alumneexclosdelhorari
presencia:controlassitencia
incidencies:entrevista
incidencies:expulsio                                      <---!
incidencies:incidencia
incidencies:incidenciadaula
seguimentTutorial:seguimenttutorial
```

Comment: That's not exactly what I'm looking for.  I believe that this lists all actual related objects.  So if there exists an object in mdl_two that links to an object in mdl_one, it will show me the model name of  that object in mdl_two.  But I want something more general.  I want to know that mdl_two can be connected to mdl_one.  So independent of an actual object (or even an actual link between two objects), I just want to list that there can be a related mdl_two object to mdl_one.  I want the user to know that this relationship CAN be defined, not that it necessarily IS defined.

Comment: So in this example (and correct me if I'm mistaken), if there is not an actual related object mdl_two for some object mdl_one, mdl_two won't be listed?

Comment: @Ed. , I have edited sample. Look if is this that you need. If not I will delete answer (or improve it if I can)